# How to prevent Redefinition of class?

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

I have been implementing a custom Vector from one of the latest C++ books and I am coming upon an error in the vector.cpp and vector.h file at the Class Vector and Vector::Vector respectively: Redefinition of 'Vector'

Here is the code for each file:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Container.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

vector.h

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s}     // constructor: acquire resources
    {
        for (int i=0; i!=s; ++i)      // initialize elements
            elem[i]=0;
            }

    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; }                  // destructor: release resources

    double& operator[](int i);
    int size() const;
private:
    double* elem;     // elem points to an array of sz doubles
    int sz;
};
```

vector.cpp

```
Vector::Vector(int s) // definition of the constructor

:elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} // initialize members
{}
double& Vector::operator[](int i) // definition of subscripting
{
    return elem[i];
}

int Vector::size() const // definition of size()
{
    return sz;
}
```

container.cpp

```
class Container {
public:
     virtual double& operator[](int) = 0;     // pure virtual function
     virtual int size() const = 0;            // const member function (§4.2.1)
     virtual ~Container() {}                  // destructor (§4.2.2)
};


class Vector_container : public Container {   // Vector_container implements Container
public:
     Vector_container(int s) : v(s) { }   // Vector of s elements
     ~Vector_container() {}

     double& operator[](int i) override { return v[i]; }
     int size() const override { return v.size(); }
private:
     Vector v;
};
```

I tried enclosing the .h file with #ifndef Vector_h,#define Vector_h, and #endif but it the error still appears in Vector_cpp. If I encapsulate Vector.cpp with #ifndef Vector_cpp, #define Vector_h, and #endif the error still appears.

To add insult to injury, when I add Vector.h to container.cpp it tells me: Unknown type name 'Vector' at the bottom where I declared Vector v

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Here is the header file for the container? :)

Comment: You do need the `#ifndef`'s for sure, in each header file. Where is your `Container.h`?

Comment: You implemented the `Vector::Vector(int s)` constructor in both the header *and* the .cpp file. Choose *one*. If your choice is the .cpp file, then strip the body and member initialization list of `Vector(int s`)` from the header, leaving only the decl in the header; just like you did with the `size()` member.

Comment: I didn't make a header file for the container. Oops!

Comment: You're defining the ctor both in the header and in the source file. Delete the definition in the header.

Comment: The error messages should also point you to specific lines. Which lines are associated with the two definitions of `Vector::Vector(int)`?

Comment: `Container.cpp` should probably just be `Container.h`, which would then include `Vector.h`. As @WhozCraig said, you're also redefining the `Vector`'s constructor.

Comment: You marked as correct incorrect answer. Correct answer is given by Vlad. #ifndef guard should be used. It  is compiler agnostic and common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a header file for your Container class as well, so you need a `Container.h` too (note this should match the name of the file). In your case, it seems that it would suffice to just rename your file, from Container.cpp, to Container.h.

Moreover, you should implement your methods (e.g. the constructor of `Vector`) into only one file, not two. For example, you would *declare* the method in the header file, and then *define* it in the source file.

---

Putting everything together, you need:

- main.cpp (no changes here)
- Container.h (and not Container.cpp, but no changes in the content of
  the file, you did a good work! :))
- Vector.h

  ```
  class Vector {
  public:
      Vector(int s);

      ~Vector();
      double& operator[](int i);
      int size() const;
  private:
      double* elem;     // elem points to an array of sz doubles
      int sz;
  };
  ```
- Vector.cpp

  ```
  #include "Vector.h"

  Vector::Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} // initialize members
  {}
  double& Vector::operator[](int i) // definition of subscripting
  {
      return elem[i];
  }

  int Vector::size() const // definition of size()
  {
      return sz;
  }

  Vector::~Vector() { delete[] elem; }
  ```

Compile:

> g++ main.cpp Vector.cpp

Comment: Hello, my friend. I fixed it like you told me to and now when I try to create the object: Container* p = new Vector_container;

Comment: it gives me the error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector_container'

Comment: @Lester, the constructor expects an integer.

Comment: Hi @Lester, good attempt (shown in your question). :) Yes, the compiler is of course right. Read the error message. You try to call the constructor **without a parameter**, while its prototype asks for an `int` parameter, the size. So you need to write `Container *p = new Vector_container(5)`, if you want 5 elements for example. Pro-tip: Make compiler your friend, it will  always be there for you (even in the most restricted areas on this planet).

Comment: Oops! Much love guys.

Answer (score 1):

1. .Common practice is following project structure below (using guards directives):

ClassName1.h

```
#ifndef CLASSNAME1_H
#define CLASSNAME1_H

// class definition
class ClassName1
{
     // ...
};

#endif
```

ClassName1.cpp

```
#include "ClassName1.h"

// implementation of ClassName1 functions may go here - except templates - templates should be defined eventually in one header file (not separate compilation unit) or one header with template body may include implementation from second header with implementation if template is big enough- extension , say - ipp. At least this is limitation for C++98.
ClassName1::someFunction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Main.cpp // or some other user code that uses ClassName1

```
#include "ClassName1.h"

ClassName1::someStaticFunction(); // for instance
ClassName1 className1; // for instance
```

Following this structure systematically with all classes you won't encounter class redefinition. this makes code portable.

2.There is another non standard way (Visual C++, GCC) - using : #pragma once directive

```
#pragma once

struct foo {
    int member;
};
```

Comment: appreciate it my friend